# How to set time of choice in a Calendar object?

Tags: android, service, calendar, alarmmanager

Sorry if the question is a bit misleading.

I asked another question earlier and by its help I got this far. Here is the problem.

I'm supposed to launch a Service at a particular time. Now... the service starts if I launch it instantly by using current time from a Calendar object, but when I set the time manually, the service doesn't launch. Here's the code:

```
    Calendar myCal = Calendar.getInstance();
    myCal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 21);
    myCal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 4);

    // Will use putExtras here to give service the details of which profile to activate
    Intent intent = new Intent(Create.this, AutoBot.class);
    PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(Create.this, 0, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, myCal.getTimeInMillis(), 5*1000, pintent);
```

Now this should technically work, but its not. And that is why I need your help :(

Also, If I have multiple triggers (alarms per se), what would the third argument of setRepeating be?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set up day month  and year as well. Date in millis is from 1 Jan 1970

Comment: But I'm initializing the Calendar object with current date/time. Why should I need to change that? And can you kindly explain what I need to put in Calendar.DATE/YEAR?

Answer (score 0):

I think this link may answer your question.  It explains a there is a limitation in 
the system where the wake lock the alarm manager holds will be released too early when 
delivering to a service.  See this discussion: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/2b98206d18a0192f/

Hope this helps.

Comment: The code works fine if I use the actual current time (using Calendar.getInstance and then using that Calendar to get current time). However, when I create another Calendar and try to set its time manually, the code refuses to work.

Comment: As the Android engineer explained in the post I referenced above, the mechanism for using an alarm manager to start a service is not reliable.  The post explains a more reliable way to accomplish that.